# Exception while Inserting Oracle DB table with Clob column in Groovy

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, groovy, clob

I'm trying to insert a file into a oracle db table by using groovy. I am using the following code:

```
import groovy.io.FileType
import groovy.sql.Sql
import oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

import java.sql.Date

final def PROJECT_DIR = "/appdata/project/pmp"
final def SCRIPT_DIR = "/scm/src/main/scripts"

// To be able to use driver...
new OracleDriver();

sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE", "PMP", "pmp")

sql.execute("delete from SCM_GROOVY_SCRIPTS")

def dir = new File(PROJECT_DIR + SCRIPT_DIR);
dir.eachFileRecurse(FileType.FILES) { file ->
    String scriptName = file.name.substring(0, file.name.indexOf('.'))
    def timestamp = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())

    println scriptName
    println timestamp

    List<Object> params = new ArrayList<>()
    params.add(scriptName)
    params.add(file.bytes)
    params.add(timestamp)

    sql.execute("INSERT INTO SCM_GROOVY_SCRIPTS (SCRIPT_NAME, SCRIPT_SOURCE, LAST_UPDATED) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", params)
}

sql.close()
```

I get the following output when I execute the code.

> ServiceUpdateRule
>
> 2016-12-28
>
> Dec 28, 2016 11:01:56 AM groovy.sql.Sql execute
>   WARNING: Failed to execute: INSERT INTO SCM_GROOVY_SCRIPTS
>   (SCRIPT_NAME, SCRIPT_SOURCE, LAST_UPDATED) VALUES (?, ?, ?) because:
>   ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column
>
> Caught: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only
>   for insert into a LONG column
>
> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for
>   insert into a LONG column
>
> ```
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:113)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:288)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:754)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:219)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:972)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1192)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3415)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3521)
>     at InsertUpdate$_run_closure1.doCall(InsertUpdate.groovy:35)
>     at InsertUpdate.run(InsertUpdate.groovy:23)
> ```

If I pass the clob argument as null instead of file.bytes, it inserts all rows without any error. The structure of my table is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE SCM_GROOVY_SCRIPTS (
        SCRIPT_NAME VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
        SCRIPT_SOURCE CLOB,
        LAST_UPDATED DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE ,
        PRIMARY KEY (SCRIPT_NAME)
);
```

In addition, the code works if I use BLOB data type instead of CLOB.

Comment: A `Clob` is a character data type, not for plain bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found a way to insert CLOB data type.

The solution is to use java.sql.Clob and oracle.sql.CLOB classes.

```
import groovy.io.FileType
import groovy.sql.Sql
import oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
import oracle.sql.CLOB

import java.sql.Clob
import java.sql.Date

final def PROJECT_DIR = "/appdata/project/pmp"
final def SCRIPT_DIR = "/scm/src/main/scripts"

// To be able to use driver...
new OracleDriver();

Sql sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE", "PMP", "pmp")

sql.execute("delete from SCM_GROOVY_SCRIPTS")

def dir = new File(PROJECT_DIR + SCRIPT_DIR);
dir.eachFileRecurse(FileType.FILES) { file ->
    String scriptName = file.name.substring(0, file.name.indexOf('.'))
    def timestamp = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())

    println scriptName
    println timestamp

    Clob clob = CLOB.createTemporary(sql.getConnection(), false, CLOB.DURATION_SESSION);
    clob.setString(1, file.getText("UTF-8"))

    List<Object> params = new ArrayList<>()
    params.add(scriptName)
    params.add(clob)
    params.add(timestamp)

    sql.execute("INSERT INTO SCM_GROOVY_SCRIPTS (SCRIPT_NAME, SCRIPT_SOURCE, LAST_UPDATED) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", params)
}

sql.close()
```